# I have requested that an OP cease emailing me

Tags: discussion, specific-user, moderation

I posted two solutions to  [About some Pythagorean Quadruples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435980/about-some-pythagorean-quadruples)

The second answer covers the situation that the OP says is of interest, ruling out values of her variable $K$ for which there is no solution to her Diophantine equation.

The OP repeatedly emails me, ignoring or misunderstanding what I have already said.

I have asked the OP to stop contacting me, in my final email and in a comment at the question. I have forwarded the (long) email thread to Mariano and Willie, moderators I know through MO.

Any assistance will be appreciated. I am not sure what in the emails can be trusted, with the exception that i think it likely the OP is Bulgarian.

Comment: Maybe you should consider not disposing your email address anymore but instead suggesting people to further discuss possible questions in the chat. Although it certainly is sad if that would be necessary.

Comment: I don't really see how moderators should/can help you with unwanted emails (even if the sender is MSE user).

Comment: I had a problem like this before, and the moderators were very useful.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, what did they do?

Comment: Have two separate e-mail addresses: One for business/work/family/important things, and another for online accounts.  That way you will never care if someone gets ahold of the email address you use on SE or other social websites.

Answer (score 19):

Add a rule that deletes emails from the said address, or sends them to the spam folder.

Comment: True, though I can imagine that the OP might also want moderators to take action. Though your suggestion is a practical solution, it doesn't rule out the fact that others might also become affected.

Comment: Hi, Asaf. I think it will work out. I did want to register my reasons for being publically rude at the original question... I do not know how to change the spam filter, although I know it is possible with this service: after Irving Kaplansky died I asked MSRI to bounce or delete all email to his address, which I had continued to check.

Comment: Asaf, forwarded you the email stuff a minute ago; 12:09 Pacific time

Comment: @Will I saw, thanks.

Comment: @WillJagy: according to your AMS-CML entry, you have two e-mail addresses. For one of them you can follow [instructions here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en), and just set a rule to send all e-mails matching a certain "From" address to trash. For the other, you can consult [this page](https://www.msri.org/web/msri/pages/60) and modify it slightly (in terms of the matching conditions) so that all mail from a given e-mail address is automatically deleted.

Comment: @WillieWong, thanks.

Comment: @WillieWong Good job man. :-)